# What does xcode mean "interoperabilityMode is unavailable"?

Tags: c++, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, xcode15

Trying to write an SPM package using the new [C++ interop features](https://www.swift.org/documentation/cxx-interop/project-build-setup/#mixing-swift-and-c-using-swift-package-manager) when I put in `swiftSettings: [.interoperabilityMode(.Cxx)])` I get the error "interoperabilityMode is unavailable" what does that mean?  Do I need to enable something in xcode settings to get the new C++ interop  stuff?

Comment: What Xcode version are you using? The linked doc page clearly states that you need Xcode 15 for mixed C++ - Swift projects.

Comment: Using XCode 15. If you try on 14 you get a different error about it not even knowing what interoperabilityMode or Cxx are, as you would expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to change the first line in the package definition to:

`// swift-tools-version: 5.9`